# Emacs: How run shell (by hotkey) from any buffer?

Tags: emacs

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1.

If I want run shell I use hotkey: **M-a shell**

It's work fine.
But how I can run shell using any hotkey from any Emacs buffer?

Comment: Does `(global-set-key (kbd "M-q") 'shell)` (replace `M-q` with a suitable hotkey) do what you want?

Comment: You can also type `M-x global-set-key` and do it interactively.

Comment: Thanks. It's work. Emacs COOL!!!